# Help interpreting magento AOE profiler results

Tags: magento-1.9, profiler, slow-response

Anything that involves **loading products** in my magento store is **very slow**. I understand that this is the case by default, but I suspect that there's a bottleneck somewhere else in my **code related to products**.

Here are my **profiler results** for editing a **configurable product** with template options :

[image: Profiler results]

I am a bit confused interpreting this. Does this mean that the bottleneck, the red part in this picture, is located in the dispatch controller? Is the solution to go through that file and figure out what is happening?

The product grid in the admin is so slow, that it doesn't even load in the profiler. It takes 10 seconds to load on the server, and the server is an optimized dedicated machine.

Comment: Any 3rd-party extensions that are used for grid modification? I see 'Xonu_SBE' there? Likely the bottleneck

Comment: I am running a few extensions. But what does the red part in the profiler mean? I understand it is "self" - does this mean that this is how long it takes to load BEFORE loading the sub-components?